# Question about Warrior mechanics

Tags: dominion, dominion-adventures

The instructions for the warrior state:

> For each Traveller you have in play (including this) each other player
>   discards the top card of his deck and trashes it if it costs $3 or $4.

So let's assume I have played some card that gives me +2 actions and I also have two warriors which I play for those two actions.

Does the attack on the first warrior take the second warrior into account (i.e. there are two travellers in play on both attacks, forcing my opponents to discard (and potentially trash) 4 cards)?

Or does the first attack only have the one warrior in play and only the second attack counts both warriors, forcing my opponents to discard 3 cards (1 + 2)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Cards are always played and resolved one at a time, so your opponents will discard (and potentially trash) a total of 3 cards.**

The specific sequence of events:

- Play a Village

  - Draw 1 card
  - Add 2 to the number of actions you can play this turn
- Play a Warrior

  - There is 1 Traveller in play (the one you just played), so each other player discard the top card of their deck and trashes it if it costs $3 or $4.
- Play another Warrior

  - There are 2 Travellers in play, so each other player does this twice: discards the top card of their deck and trashes it if it costs $3 or $4.

The first Warrior will be completely done with everything it does (except being exchanged when discarded) before anything in the game knows you are going to play a second Warrior.